# Copenhagen Airport -- International to Schengen connection?

Tags: schengen, airport-transfer, cph

I am flying **into CPH from Singapore** arriving in **Terminal 3 at 7:10am** and will be changing to a **Norwegian Air flight to Oslo** that departs at **9:20am from Terminal 2**.

I realise that I will need to go through Passport Control and Security because I am entering Schengen.

**Question:** How much additional effort would it require if I have a checked-in bag compared to a carry-on bag?

I don't think I can check the bag the entire way (due to a change of airline), so will I need to go 'out' and back 'into' the airport? If I only have a carry-on bag, would the process be much simpler?

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, the last time I flew from Copenhagen, it took about 30 minutes just to get through security. I would not risk that connection even without checked luggage.

Comment: Note bag drop / gate closure deadlines here https://www.norwegian.com/uk/travel-info/check-in-and-boarding/check-in-deadlines/

Comment: I like that page... "If you are travelling with animals, weapons or musical instruments" -- What an interesting grouping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How much additional effort would it require if I have a checked-in bag compared to a carry-on bag?

If you booked this as a single itinerary the answer is "none" and there is no need to read any further.

However, this sounds like a self-connection (i.e. two separate bookings). In this case you have to pick up your bags, carry them through customs and bring them to the Norwegian check in counter or bag drop.

It's not so much about effort but about timing. You already have a very short layover for an international self-connection. Bringing checked luggage will significantly increase the risk of missing your second flight. If you do, you are "no-show" and may have to buy a same-day ticket which can be quite expensive.

Personally, I wouldn't do this, but everyone's risk tolerance is different.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the flights are on separate bookings, hence my worry. If Singapore Airlines (my first carrier) is willing to check the bag through to my final destination, would I still need to pass through customs and re-enter the airport or could I stay on the secure side of the airport? Just trying to to figure out the simplest process.

Comment: Singapore Airlines will not check your bags through since Norwegian isn't one of their interline partners (https://milelion.com/2022/10/19/which-carriers-does-singapore-airlines-interline-with/)

Answer (score 2):

With luggage you need to collect it and haul it to terminal 2, it's roughly a 10 minute walk. Then print luggage tags and use the bag drop (I recommend you to use the smaller luggage tag printers instead of check in machines if you've checked in online). Then you need to go through security again, but security lines are most often shorter than the bag drop deadline.

Without checked luggage you can walk straight to the gate once you've passed immigration. There is only one terminal airside, terminal numbers are only for check-in.

Comment: Ah! That's exactly what I needed to know. So carry-on greatly reduces the process. Thank you!

Comment: **Result:** I took carry-on baggage and walked from my plane to Security. I was past Passport Control within a few minutes and had plenty of time to visit the Aviator Lounge using my Priority Pass before heading to my next flight. Using carry-on baggage helped throughout my trip on flights, trains and even in hotel rooms (that can be rather small). This was helped by using vacuum bags that reduced the size of my items to fit in a carry-on bag. Thank you all for the advice!